# VBA Webscrape not picking up elmenents; pick up frames/tables?

Tags: vba, excel, tags, web-scraping

Tried asking this question. Didn't get many answers. Can't install things onto my work computer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805065/vba-webscrape-not-picking-up-elements

Want to scrape a morningstar page into Excel with the code below. Problem is, it doesn't feed any real elements/data back. I actually just want the Dividend and cap gain distribution table really from that link I put into my_Page.

This is usually easiest way, but an entire page scrape way, AND Excel-->Data-->From Web DON'T work.

I've tried to use get elements by tag name and class before, but I failed at being able to do it in this case.This might be the way to go... Once again, just want that Dividend and Cap Gain distribution table. Not seeing any results in via the Debug.print

Working code below, just need to parse into excel. Updated attempt below:

```
Sub Macro1()


    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/fundquote/f?&t=ANNPX&culture=en_us&platform=RET&viewId1=2046632524&viewId2=3141452350&viewId3=3475652630"
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = IE.document



    'For Each Table In doc.getElementsByClassName("gr_table_b1")

    'For Each td In Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each td In doc.getElementsByClassName("gr_table_row4")
    Debug.Print td.Cells(5).innerText
    'Debug.Print td.Cells(1).innerText
    Next td
    'Next Table


    'IE.Quit
         'Application.EnableEvents = True



  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The content in question is contained within an iframe.  You can see this by right clicking on that section of the sebsite, and selecting `Inspect element`.  Looking up the tree, you'll see an iframe tag, containing the url of data.  You should try to find that element, and extract that url (which is generated with [js](/questions/tagged/js)) and then open that page.

Comment: My current environment has an old version of IE, which does not render the page properly, so I cannot build something to actually do this.

Comment: iframe is this http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/fundquote/f?&t=ANNPX&culture=en_us&platform=RET&viewId1=2046632524&viewId2=3141452350&viewId3=3475652630. My debug yields something now (It just says "YTD"). I think if I can get those tags correct I'll be in business now.

Comment: @pjhollow Just so you know.  I got a different URL on my end.  The viewIDs seam to be generated by the [tag:js].  I'm not sure what will happen if you hard code those values.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Mind pasting what URL you are seeing?

Comment: @pjhollow http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/fundquote/f?&t=ANNPX&culture=en_us&platform=RET&viewId1=2311722111&viewId2=3606113235&viewId3=3155242666

Answer (score 0):

No frame to worry about. You only need the table id.

---

**Webpage view:**

[image: Web view]

---

**Print out from code:**

[image: Code print out]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDivAndCapTable()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, hTable As HTMLTable
    Const URL = "http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/fundquote/f?&t=ANNPX&culture=en_us&platform=RET&viewId1=2046632524&viewId2=3141452350&viewId3=3475652630"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ie
        .Visible = True

        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .READYSTATE < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set hTable = .document.getElementById("DividendAndCaptical")
        WriteTable hTable, 1
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, R As Long, C As Long, tBody As Object
    R = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(R, C).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    C = C + 1
                Next td
                R = R + 1
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```